# Some suggestions to solve an array of structs and the realloc in it

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct

```c
struct object{
    double x, y, size;
    int ident;
}
```

and the function

```c
int object_read_from_file(struct object* s, FILE* f);
```

which reads some data from one Line of a .txt File and saves it in the struct object. P.e.:  "0.1894 0.3442 0.9 26" could be one line of the .txt File.
This is all in the File "object.c".
In the File "main.c" I have now to implement, to read in all objects from a large .txt File with many (not known before programm starts) lines with name "arg[3]" and save them in an array "objects" in the order they are read in.
My first try is this:

```c
FILE* f = fopen(arg[3], "r");
struct object s;
int x = 0;
s* objects;
objects = calloc(1, sizeof(struct object));

while(object_read_from_file(&s, f) !=0)
{
    objects[x].x = s->x;
    objects[x].y = s->y;
    objects[x].size = s->size;
    objects[x].ident = s->ident;
    objects = realloc(objects, ((x+1) * (sizeof(struct object))));
    x++;
}
fclose(f);
```

I know that there is no saving to my array "objects" here. That is because I now allready have multiple errors at compiling like "->" is an invalid type argument and "objects" is undeclared. I have absolutely no idea what i am doing wrong and I would love to get some help or either to get some better idea of solving the task another way then my way.

Comment: By looking at this line `s* objects;
` I can tell that you need a good `C` book. What is `s` ? It is not type as you think but a variable.

Comment: i have to admit that our script we got to learn everything is missing a lot... not even "calloc" is mentioned in the whole script, i got it from the internet, so maybe you are right

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes, I removed my remark ;-)

Comment: @bruno but do I not need to give the "struct object" a variable to pass this to the object_read_from_file(&s, f) function as "&s"?

Comment: @Neolog look at my answer

Comment: @kiranBiradar First thank you for writing me. Then: in the function to read from file i save the with `fscanf(f, "%le %le %le %d %le %d", &x, &y, &z, &h, &size, &hr);` read variables like this `s->x = x` and so I thought in main I could access them via `s->x` ?

Comment: What you really need to do is to read about structs, arrays and pointers. I'm sorry to say it, but this code is completely flawed. Just fixing it wouldn't teach you much and pointing out all misunderstandings would yield a very long answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must be :

```
FILE* f = fopen(arg[3], "r");
struct object s;
int x = 0;
struct object * objects = malloc(0);

while(object_read_from_file(&s, f) !=0)
{
    objects = realloc(objects, ((x+1) * (sizeof(struct object))));
    objects[x].x = s.x;
    objects[x].y = s.y;
    objects[x].size = s.size;
    objects[x].ident = s.ident;
    x++;
}
fclose(f);
```

the first *malloc* is here to allow a *realloc* after, and the *realloc* must be done *before* to save the new entry. Of course because *s* is not a pointer `->` must be replaced by `.`

If was better to check *f* is not *NULL* after the *fopen*

Considering the definition of *object* you can use *memcpy* to set the new entry from *s*

Comment: No need for a `malloc`. Just set `objects` to NULL. BTW: `realloc` directly into the target is a risk

Comment: @4386427 sure is better to check the return of _realloc_, but in a lot of cases if you have not enough memory it is difficult to continue ;-) For the _fopen_ this is different, to produce a message indicating "cannot open xxx" helps a lot

Comment: "s is not a pointer." that turned me upside down... of course not...i am so blind sometimes ^^ thank you!

Comment: @Neolog so many times the more it is visible the less we see :-D